# How to get the bar names from Google Chart api

Tags: javascript, web, google-visualization

I am stuck for a couple of days!

I making an app that show cat breeds and when they are discovered in europe.

This is my code:

Since I can't post my code here because the forum want to reformat it.

Check my Google drive:

**My code**
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wiwgFI3tGimvXKzOinLUZMYXAaMVscECeQopiyEHB98/edit?usp=sharing

And It returns a good looking chart that looks like this: 
[image: The Chart]

What I trying to do is getting the name that's inside a bar of the timeline.
As an example, if I click on "pers(ion)" , I want to make dynamicaly a div with more information about the pers(ion). But because it doesn't get a class or id I can't get it.

Does anybody now an easy way do do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you get the name of the BAR.
If you data is

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Object', 'Count'],
    ["ApexClass", apexCount],
    ["Sobjects", objectCount],
    ["ApexPage", vfPageCount],
    ["Role", rolesCount],
    ["Dashboard", dashboardCount],
    ["Profile", profileCount]

    ]);
```

Then in select Handler write this

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(barchart, 'select', countsChartSelectListener);
    function countsChartSelectListener(){
        var selectedItem = barchart.getSelection()[0];
        if (selectedItem) {
            var barName = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. It looks like you have the `select` handler setup properly.
In this example, I update the div, `userSelect`, when the chart is selected.

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["timeline"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var container;
var chart;
var dataTable;

function drawChart() {
  container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
}

function selectHandler() {
  var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
  if (selectedItem) {
    var topping = dataTable.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
    document.getElementById('userSelect').innerHTML = 'The user selected ' + topping;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;"></div>

<div id="userSelect"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in my example I always got "rassen" , which means breed. In your example you have 3 (Washinton, Adam, Jefferson)** rows** ** in column 0**, I got only 1 ("Rassen") row. 

What I want to do is creating a div with more information for the selected breed.

 Here's the JSON file if it would helps:
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwrWbgQz17mBbkFyemU3clEyeVk

Comment: JSON would help, but it says I need permission. can you post a few rows in your question? you can add row properties, if you need to store an id in the chart for reference back to the table...